# Traefik equivalent for proxy_read_timeout in Nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, traefik

We are using **Traefik 2.1.3** as [Kubernetes Ingress Controller](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/).
Replacing an **Nginx** we are unable to mimic the option:

```
proxy_read_timeout 60s;
```

I would have expected a [Middleware](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/overview/) for this task but there isn't.

Is there an alternative? Ideas?

Comment: have you tried `transport.respondingTimeouts.readTimeout` ? check [Traefik Responding Timeouts](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#respondingtimeouts) documentation.

Comment: yes, but that is for an entire **Entrypoint** we have to set this on a specific **Route**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Unfortunately there is no mention on this specific feature in Traefik documentations.**

The closest match is the `transport.respondingTimeouts.readTimeout` as I mentioned.

- There is a request for this explanation on Github: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4580,

It's still open but is stalled since March 2019 so It looks like it can be done but there is nowhere saying how.

I'd suggest you stay with Nginx or rethink your cycle strategy to fit your current needs while waiting for Traefik updates on this.

Comment: looking forward for the implementation of that issue. Thanks, I will provide an updates if any.